# Añadir variable para indicar cantidad

Tags: javascript, javascript-metodo

He logrado identificar los meses con más de 7 letras pero ahora estoy atascado con la variable númerica para señalar que son 3.

```js
const monthsname = ['enero', 'febrero', 'marzo', 'abril', 'mayo', 'junio', 'julio', 'agosto', 'septiembre', 'octubre', 'noviembre', 'diciembre']
const longMonths = monthsname
.filter(monthsname => monthsname.length > 7)
.map(monthsname => monthsname.toUpperCase())
console.log("Los meses con más de 7 letras son: " + longMonths)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

puedes usar la propiedad .length para contar el número de elementos en el array resultante de longMonths. Seria asi:

```js
const monthsname = ['enero', 'febrero', 'marzo', 'abril', 'mayo', 'junio', 'julio', 'agosto', 'septiembre', 'octubre', 'noviembre', 'diciembre']
const longMonths = monthsname
.filter(monthsname => monthsname.length > 7)
.map(monthsname => monthsname.toUpperCase())
console.log("Hay " + longMonths.length + " meses con más de 7 letras: " + longMonths);
```

Comment: @Alfonso Recuerda marcar la pregunta como aceptada si te ha sido de ayuda